# Countdown javascript function with variable target date

Tags: php, javascript, date, countdown

Hello Guys and Gals,
    I am trying to have  (1) a javascript countdown function (2) a countdown function that accepts a php variable target date(e.g. 4 seconds after the user clicks 'start') (3) an onclick() to run both the stopstart() and updateAlarmTime() functions.

This is what I use for base code: http://stopwatch.onlineclock.net/

On my main php page I have:

```
<script src="js/stopwatch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<?php $alarmsecond2=4; ?>

<form name='stopwatch'....
<input type='button' onclick='stopstart()'  onfocus='this.blur()' 
name='startstopbutton' id='startstopbutton' ... value='Start'> 
</form>
```

stopstart() works as written above, updateAlarmTime() works if I use pulldown select menus to set the time variable, e.g. $alarmsecond2, but I don't want that.

I tried calling stopstart() and updateAlarmTime('') with one onclick(), but only stopstart executes. I also tried calling a function to call both stopstart() and updateAlarmTime() with onclick() but that also didn't work.

In stopwatch.js I have:

```
function stopstart() {

t[t[2]]=(new Date()).valueOf();
t[2]=1-t[2];

if (0==t[2]) {
    clearInterval(t[4]);
    t[3]+=t[1]-t[0];
    document.getElementById("startstopbutton").value="Start";
    document.getElementById('split').innerHTML+=
        (t[7]++)+' Stop: '+format(t[1]-t[0])+'<br>';
    t[4]=t[1]=t[0]=0;
    disp();
    firstsplitflag = 0;
} else {
    document.getElementById("startstopbutton").value="Stop";
    t[4]=setInterval(disp, 43);
}
//GA
urchinTracker('http://stopwatch.onlineclock.net/conversions/stopstartbutton'); 
}


function updateAlarmTime()
{
var hour1 = alarmhour1;
var hour2 = ahour2;
var minute1 = aminute1;
var minute2 = aminute2;
var second1 = asecond1;
var second2 = asecond2;
var second_10th = asecond_10th;
var second_100th = asecond_100th;
var second_1000th = asecond_1000th;

alarmTime = (hour1 + hour2 + minute1 + minute2 + second1 + 
second2 + second_10th + second_100th + second_1000th);

}
```

How do I accomplish my three objectives?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: it would be much easier to implement with one.

Comment: http://stopwatch.onlineclock.net/ is the functioning code, without the variable target date. Is this what you are asking for?

Answer (score 0):

> I tried calling stopstart() and updateAlarmTime('') with one onclick(), but only stopstart executes.

Use the comma operator:

```
onclick='stopstart(), updateAlarmTime()'
```

> I also tried calling a function to call both stopstart() and updateAlarmTime() with onclick() but that also didn't work.

Use a named function, for instance `foo()`:

```
onclick='foo()'
```

Which is defined as such:

```
<script>
function foo()
  {
  stopstart();
  updateAlarmTime();
  }
</script>
```